# GROUP BY in Django Queries

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Dear StackOverFlow community:

I need your help in executing following SQL query.

```
select DATE(creation_date), COUNT(creation_date) from blog_article WHERE creation_date BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE() GROUP BY DATE(creation_date) AND author="scott_tiger";
```

Here is my Django Model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    author = models.CharField(...)
    creation_date = models.DateField(...)
```

How can I form aforementioned Django query using aggregate() and annotate() functions. I created something like this -

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date_diff = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(-30)
records = Article.objects.values('creation_date', Count('creation_date')).aggregate(Count('creation_date')).filter(author='scott_tiger', created_at__gt=date_diff, created_at__lte=now)
```

When I run this query it gives me following error -

```
'Count' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any idea who to use it?

Comment: Why are you doing *Count('creation_date')*?  SQL count doesn't really apply to a column in the result set.

Comment: But it can, and perhaps it's more readable to explicitly state what the author wants to be counting.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Count('creation_date') from values and add annotate(Count('creation_date')) after filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
records = Article.objects.filter(author='scott_tiger', created_at__gt=date_diff, 
    created_at__lte=now).values('creation_date').aggregate(
    ccd=Count('creation_date')).values('creation_date', 'ccd')
```

You need to use `creation_date__count` or customized name(`ccd` here) to refer the count result column, after `aggregate()`.
Also, `values()` before `aggregate` limits `group by` columns and last `value()` declares the columns to be `select`ed. There is no need to group by `COUNT` which is based on group of rows already.